# Convert SwiftUI View to PDF on iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, swiftui

I was drawing some nice graphs with SwiftUI, because it is so simple and easy to do. Then I wanted to export the whole SwiftUI View to a PDF such that someone else can view the graphs in a nice way. 
SwiftUI does not offer a solution for this directly.

Cheers, 
Alex

Comment: Has anyone been able to get multiple pdf pages from a ScrowView or just a scrollable content?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some thinking I came up with the idea of combining the UIKit to PDF method and SwiftUI.

At first you create your SwiftUI view, then you put into an UIHostingController. You render the HostingController on a window behind all other views and and draw its layer on a PDF. 
Sample code is listed below.

```swift
func exportToPDF() {

    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let outputFileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SwiftUI.pdf")

    //Normal with
    let width: CGFloat = 8.5 * 72.0
    //Estimate the height of your view
    let height: CGFloat = 1000
    let charts = ChartsView()

    let pdfVC = UIHostingController(rootView: charts)
    pdfVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

    //Render the view behind all other views
    let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
    rootVC?.addChild(pdfVC)
    rootVC?.view.insertSubview(pdfVC.view, at: 0)

    //Render the PDF
    let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 8.5 * 72.0, height: height))

    do {
        try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { (context) in
            context.beginPage()
            pdfVC.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
        })

        self.exportURL = outputFileURL
        self.showExportSheet = true

    }catch {
        self.showError = true
        print("Could not create PDF file: \(error)")
    }

    pdfVC.removeFromParent()
    pdfVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Got the view but no text

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution provides PDF with rasterized text. That means the: 1. text can't be selected as a text from PDF. 2. Text not looks as crispy as a vector-based text

Answer (score 10):

I loved this answer, but couldn't get it to work. I was getting an exception and the catch wasn't being executed.

After some head scratching, and writing up a SO Question asking how to debug it (which I never submitted), I realized that the solution, while not obvious, was simple: wrap the rendering phase in an async call to the main queue:

```
//Render the PDF

 let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 8.5 * 72.0, height: height))
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
     do {
         try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { (context) in
             context.beginPage()
             pdfVC.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
         })
         print("wrote file to: \(outputFileURL.path)")
     } catch {
         print("Could not create PDF file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
     }
 }
```

Thanks, SnOwfreeze!

Comment: That's a good adoption. I think this might be handled different depending on the SwiftUI / Xcode version. I had similar issues when I updated to a newer Xcode version

Comment: I try this in Swift Playground but still got 'expression failed to parse, unknown error' do have any idea ? Which Xcode version are you using ? thanks

Comment: Did you remember to "import PDFKit" ?

Comment: Yes, I just had to replace `pdfVC.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)` by `rootVC.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)` to make it works

Answer (score 4):

I tried all the answers, but they didn't work for me (Xcode 12.4, iOS 14.4). Here is what's worked for me:

```
import SwiftUI

func exportToPDF() {
    let outputFileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("SwiftUI.pdf")
    let pageSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    
    //View to render on PDF
    let myUIHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
    myUIHostingController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pageSize)
    
    
    //Render the view behind all other views
    guard let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController else {
        print("ERROR: Could not find root ViewController.")
        return
    }
    rootVC.addChild(myUIHostingController)
    //at: 0 -> draws behind all other views
    //at: UIApplication.shared.windows.count -> draw in front
    rootVC.view.insertSubview(myUIHostingController.view, at: 0)
    
    
    //Render the PDF
    let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pageSize))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        do {
            try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { (context) in
                context.beginPage()
                myUIHostingController.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
            })
            print("wrote file to: \(outputFileURL.path)")
        } catch {
            print("Could not create PDF file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        //Remove rendered view
        myUIHostingController.removeFromParent()
        myUIHostingController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Note: Don't try to use this function in a view with .onAppear when you try to export the same view. This will result in a endless loop naturally.

Answer (score 1):

### iOS 16+

**2022 Update**

Starting from iOS 16 we can use `ImageRenderer` to create a PDF from a View with pure SwiftUI. There's no need for using UIKit anymore.

Here is an example:

```
@MainActor
func createPDF() -> URL? {
    guard let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        return nil
    }
    let url = directory
        .appendingPathComponent("MyPDF")
        .appendingPathExtension(for: .pdf)
    var box = CGRect(
        origin: .zero,
        size: .init(width: 595, height: 842) // A4 sheet
    )
    let metadata: [CFString: String] = [:]

    guard let context = CGContext(url as CFURL, mediaBox: &box, metadata as CFDictionary) else {
        return nil
    }

    drawPDF(in: context)

    return url
}
```

```
@MainActor
func drawPDF(in context: CGContext) {
    let view = MyView()

    context.beginPDFPage(nil)
    let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: view)
    renderer.render { _, renderer in
        renderer(context)
    }
    context.endPDFPage()
    context.closePDF()
}
```

Comment: When I implement this, my view becomes so much smaller than the PDF frame, any ideas?

Comment: @benpomeroy9 Did you also enlarge the view frame? The idea is to make the view bigger and then scale it down using `UIGraphicsPDFRenderer` without changing the PDF page size.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other methods above but still had issues with the view showing properly, so here is what I have that works for me on Xcode 12.2 & Swift 5 after messing with both [Sn0wfreeze's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60753437/8697793) & [pawello2222's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64089352/14861538):

```
func exportToPDF() {
    let outputFileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("SwiftUI.pdf")
    let pageSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController

    //Render the PDF
    let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pageSize))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        do {
            try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { (context) in
                context.beginPage()
                rootVC?.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
            })
            print("wrote file to: \(outputFileURL.path)")
        } catch {
            print("Could not create PDF file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I removed any reference to a newly created "pdfVC" view controller, and only referenced the main view the entire time as our "rootVC". I grab the screen width and height and use that to define our PDF's width and height, rather than trying to scale the view to proper A4 or letter size. This creates a PDF of the entire showing SwiftUI view.

Hope this helps anyone that had any issues with the other answers! :)

Comment: Where's the file located? 

I have a path but I cannot enter to see my file... Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can get it by downloading the container from devices. its in the documents folder. But yhe problem with this solution is that it will not size to page sizes that are not the same aspect ratio as the screen - which is the case all current device screen sizes. also the rendering is a bit not right.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func exportToPDF() {
    let listHeight: CGFloat = 24.0//or you can get it from your ListView
    let rowsCount = yourArrayOrObject.count
        let rowsCountPerPage = Int(11.69 * 72 / listHeight) - 6
        let countOfPages = Int(ceil( Double(rowsCount) / Double(rowsCountPerPage)))
    
    var index = 0
    while index < countOfPages {
        
    let items = yourArrayOrObject.slice(size: rowsCountPerPage)[index]
    
        let rootView =  List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item.name)")
            }
    }
        
        let dpiScale: CGFloat = 1.5
        
        // for US letter page size
        // let pageSize = CGSize(width: 8.5 * 72, height: 11 * 72)
        // for A4 page size
        let pageSize = CGSize(width: 8.27 * 72, height: 11.69 * 72)
        
        //View to render on PDF
        let myUIHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
        myUIHostingController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pageSize * dpiScale)
        myUIHostingController.view.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light//it will be light, when dark mode
        //Render the view behind all other views
        guard let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController else {
            print("ERROR: Could not find root ViewController.")
            return
        }
        rootVC.addChild(myUIHostingController)
        //at: 0 -> draws behind all other views
        //at: UIApplication.shared.windows.count -> draw in front
        rootVC.view.insertSubview(myUIHostingController.view, at: 0)
        
        
        //Render the PDF
        let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pageSize))
    let data = pdfRenderer.pdfData { context in
        context.beginPage()

        context.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1 / dpiScale, y: 1 / dpiScale)
        myUIHostingController.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
    }
        //Remove rendered view
        myUIHostingController.removeFromParent()
        myUIHostingController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        if index == 0 {
    pdfDocumentData = data // pdfDocumentData must be declared above: @State private var pdfDocumentData = Data()(don't forget import PDFKit)
        } else {
            pdfDocumentData =  mergePdf(data: pdfDocumentData, otherPdfDocumentData: data).dataRepresentation()!
        }
        index += 1
    }
   
    writeDataToTemporaryDirectory(withFilename: "YourPDFFileName.pdf", data: pdfDocumentData)
  
}

private func writeDataToTemporaryDirectory(withFilename: String, data: Data)  {
        do {
            // name the file
            let temporaryFileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent(withFilename)
            print("writeDataToTemporaryDirectory at url:\t\(temporaryFileURL)")
            try data.write(to: temporaryFileURL, options: .atomic)
           print("It's Ok!")//you can open file in sheet: (self.showReport = true) ,for example
            pdfDocumentData = Data()
          
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
  
    }
func mergePdf(data: Data, otherPdfDocumentData: Data) -> PDFDocument {
    // get the pdfData
    let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(data: data)!
    let otherPdfDocument = PDFDocument(data: otherPdfDocumentData)!
    
    // create new PDFDocument
    let newPdfDocument = PDFDocument()

    // insert all pages of first document
    for p in 0..<pdfDocument.pageCount {
    let page = pdfDocument.page(at: p)!
        newPdfDocument.insert(page, at: newPdfDocument.pageCount)
    }

    // insert all pages of other document
    for q in 0..<otherPdfDocument.pageCount {
        let page = otherPdfDocument.page(at: q)!
        newPdfDocument.insert(page, at: newPdfDocument.pageCount)
    }
    return newPdfDocument
}
```

Works for **XCode 13, iOS 15**,  It's multi pages solution

**pdfDocumentData must be declared above: @State private var pdfDocumentData = Data() (don't forget import PDFKit)**
Thanks [pawello2222](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8697793/pawello2222)

here are some required extensions

```
extension CGSize {
static func * (size: CGSize, value: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: size.width * value, height: size.height * value)
   }
}
extension Array {
func slice(size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
    (0...(count / size)).map{Array(self[($0 * size)..<(Swift.min($0 * size + size, count))])}
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you convert a view like ContentView() that has a scrollable content with this solution? How will you determine the `rowCounts` if the view does not have any rows?

Comment: Function must be in ContentView(), and maybe: let rootView = self