# How to export a SwiftUI View to PDF (Vector)

Tags: macos, pdf, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI View which contains Images and Borders.
I'd like to export this to a Vector-PDF.

I tried

```
let pdfExportView =  = NSHostingView(rootView: MySwiftUIView())
let pdfData = pdfExportView.dataWithPDF(inside: pdfExportView.bounds)
```

But the PDF does not contain the Images and the borders. Is there any other solution? PDF as Bitmap is not an option.

Comment: I also tried CoreGraphics with drawing the layer in the CGContext … without any luck: Result was a white PDF.
Also I tried to use printing but the result was same as
```dataWithPDF()```
Text and BezierPath had been drawn, Borders and Images not.

Comment: Used on of my DTS I got the reply to file a bug … which I did :)

But I also found a workaround: While CoreGraphics was not working first, I found out that a PDF with all SwiftUI-Elements is produced if the CoreGraphics-part is wrapped in `DispatchQueue.main.async` 
The result is flipped and mirrored but that shouldn't be a problem.
And yes, I included the workaround in the sample project which I attached to the bug report.

Comment: Same problem :/ I cannot export a PDF with images, only texts.

Comment: This should solve your problem. I tried it, and it does what it is expected to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60753436/convert-swiftui-view-to-pdf-on-ios

Comment: you said "PDF as Bitmap is not an option." I can not understand it, PDF cannot be Bitmap it is Vector from bace, what did you try to say?

Comment: How did you solve this? I can't believe you are teasing us (and also people in Apple Dev forums) that you got the solution but do not share :(

Comment: @orschaef I provided the solution in my comment from Jul 24. I wrapped the core-graphics part in `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: @ioscoder You are right - PDF is vector-based, but you still can render texts as an image and that is what's happening when you use `UIGraphicsPDFRenderer` to render the whole `SwiftUI View` into PDF context. All `Text` views are exported as bitmap images.