# Increase resolution of PDFRenderer - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, pdfkit

I am exporting a PDF through a PDF Renderer and it all works well, however if I go to print the .pdf then it becomes a bit grainy and blurry. Is there any way I can increase the resolution of the file and make it a bit clearer when printed? Please see below the setup for the PDF Renderer:

```
let charts = MatchReportView(homeTeam: homeTeam, awayTeam: awayTeam)

let pdfVC = UIHostingController(rootView: charts)
let width: CGFloat = 720
let height: CGFloat = pdfVC.view.sizeThatFits(
      CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height
pdfVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)


let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
rootVC?.addChild(pdfVC)
rootVC?.view.insertSubview(pdfVC.view, at: 0)

let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, posted my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64089352/8697793