# Create a PDF file from a specific View

Tags: ios, pdf, swiftui

I would like to create a PDF file from a View X. The code reported and extracted from Alex's question works but creates a PDF of the Main View only (View A). How can I tell him to create a PDF of the View X?

[Convert SwiftUI View to PDF on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60753436/convert-swiftui-view-to-pdf-on-ios/66024278#66024278)

```
// From Main View A
func savePdf() {
        let view = ViewX() // <--- This is the View I would like to transform, not linked to View A
        let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let outputFileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("ViewX.pdf")

        let dpiScale: CGFloat = 4

        // for A5 page size inches * 72
        let pageSize = CGSize(width: 5.8 * 72, height: 8.3 * 72)
        
        let pdfVC = UIHostingController(rootView: view) 
        pdfVC.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pageSize * dpiScale)

        let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
        rootVC?.addChild(pdfVC)
        rootVC?.view.insertSubview(pdfVC.view, at: 0)

        let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pageSize))

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do {
                try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { (context) in
                    context.beginPage()
                    rootVC?.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
                    self.pdfURL = outputFileURL
                })
            } catch {
                print("error.localizedDescription")
            }
        }
        pdfVC.removeFromParent()
        pdfVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer of the linked question:

> You render the HostingController on a window behind all other views and and draw its layer on a PDF.

That would be the first view, index 0 I presume. From the function you gave, this line looks relevant:

```swift
rootVC?.view.insertSubview(pdfVC.view, at: 0)
```

Replace `0` with your desired view.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This is what's worked for me:

```
import SwiftUI

func exportToPDF() {
    let outputFileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("SwiftUI.pdf")
    let pageSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    
    //View to render on PDF
    let myUIHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
    myUIHostingController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pageSize)
    
    
    //Render the view behind all other views
    guard let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController else {
        print("ERROR: Could not find root ViewController.")
        return
    }
    rootVC.addChild(myUIHostingController)
    //at: 0 -> draws behind all other views
    //at: UIApplication.shared.windows.count -> draw in front
    rootVC.view.insertSubview(myUIHostingController.view, at: 0)
    
    
    //Render the PDF
    let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pageSize))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        do {
            try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { (context) in
                context.beginPage()
                myUIHostingController.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
            })
            print("wrote file to: \(outputFileURL.path)")
        } catch {
            print("Could not create PDF file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        //Remove rendered view
        myUIHostingController.removeFromParent()
        myUIHostingController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Note: Don't try to use this function in a view with .onAppear when you try to export the same view. This will result in a endless loop naturally.

I hope this helps!