# How to convert office documents to pdf in swift 5 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pdf-generation, ms-office, docx

I would like to get just the page count of office documents: doc, docx, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx formats in swift 5 on iOS. It has been incredibly difficult to find any documentation or solution on this. I have tried to use webkit's webView to load the document and try to manipulate it to get the pageNumber from it but it always return zero (0). So now I have decided to find a way to convert the files into pdf so I can call the pageCount property of PDFDocument in order to get the page count but I am still not able to get around this.

Comment: What would you find if you run a search for 'swift read docx files'?

Comment: @ElTomato I have come across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60753436/convert-swiftui-view-to-pdf-on-ios where I plan to show the files in quicklook preview and then save that view a pdf. Then I can just get the pageCount of the pdf however, this SO answer only generates single page pdf document which doesn't fit my case. Any update to that answer where I can generate multiple pdf pages from a scrollable content will do the job for me!

Answer (score -3):

Office documents are in a proprietary format. There might not be an official solution. I would suggest searching for a third party library that reverse-engineers the file format and lets you query information like the number of pages.